# cron job scripts for how to set it

Tags: php

I need to perform a daily download directly from the web server, then I thought to activate the cron function that is supported by the server. I put a script in php so

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/donwload.txt');
?>
```

When I call the script for the test, I expect to find in the folder where there is' the script, even the downloaded files but rather not waste anything, obviously I'm wrong, Aas I can do this?

Comment: Can you describe what you've written, what you expect to happen, and what is happening? It looks like you've just defined `$file` which has the contents of `http://www.example.com/donwload.txt` but does nothing with it (assuming that domain isn't blocked).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and I apologize for my English through google translated, if I understand what he writes, I would like to download the file when download.txt launch the script, the web server supports cron job function and it would be useful to do auomaticamente every day at a certain time.

Comment: Please start by reading the documentation of the tools you want to use instead of wild try-and-guess orgies... The documentation explains in a _precise_ manner what the functions do and offer good examples:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Where are you hung up though? Does this script not work? Does the CRON not work?

Comment: The documentation altervista.org server tells me that for the cron function should I use a php script

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086295/how-do-i-run-a-server-script-at-a-specific-time-which-is-stored-in-mysql-databas/43087179#43087179), so my suggestion was

If you are using PHP, you can create a function and will be invoked through CLI. Then you need to add it in the crontab.

example index.php

```
<?php

//Get the data from the mysql table and process
```

$data = getDataFromTable();

```
 if ($data['user_defined_time'] == date('H') // Current Hour
    echo "Foo Bar"; //send email

    ?>
```

To test this, open your terminal and run the command php -f index.php

Add this to the crontab. In your terminal type crontab -e and edit the line to :

Run your script every hour

0 * * * * php -f /location/of/php/file/index.php